# sonar-maven-plugin for sonarqube 4.5.5 LTS is missing from maven central repository

Tags: sonarqube-4.5

The latest sonar maven plugin which can be found on the maven central repository is the 4.5.4 (see http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.codehaus.sonar%22%20AND%20a%3A%22sonar-maven-plugin%22)

Answer (score 1):

The version 4.5.5 it has been made available.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reaction. I've downloaded at run successful.